# saving PDFs for later manipulation in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, adobe, acrobat, plaintext

I have a PDF with some text in it that I would like to modify dynamically using PHP.  This is being done already with another PDF, and what happens is that PHP simply replaces a token in the form `%token%` with another value pulled from a database. If you open that PDF in a text editor, you can find the %token% in plain text.  But with this other PDF that I want to do the same thing with, if you open it in a text editor, there are no tokens in plaintext (even though I explicitly created one using Adobe Acrobat Pro).  Obviously, the PDF's string content in this PDF is either encrypted, compressed, or both.  What I want to know is how can I save a PDF so that the string content remains as plaintext such that PHP can manipulate it.

Please note, I do not want to dynamically create the whole PDF from scratch using some PHP library. I know that is something that can be done, but the PDF I am working with already exists and I just want to modify it slightly in the manner described.

Comment: You can't modify PDF with only PHP. You need some extra libraries to do that.. Also make your question clear.

Comment: How would you suggest I make my question "clear"? I thought I explained this in agonizing detail.  "Other libraries" -- are these PHP libraries? If so, then, yes, you'd be modifying the PDF with only PHP.  Furthermore, as I clearly described in excellent English, the thing I am hoping to do has already been done with another PDF file, so it IS possible. Thanks!

Comment: You might be clear. I don't understood it properly. Hope someone does.

Answer (score 0):

For things like that I like to use the free command line tool PDFtk, which can compress / decompress PDFs and some nice thinks more. You may have a look at: https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

PS: I edit a special pdf calendar form from the internet. I decompress it and replace the awful pink color for the weekend with gray (Saturday) and blue for Sunday. Violet I use as small bar to mark vacation days.